How can I display a vector and a matrix repeatedly when using fprintf
I am trying to make a multiplication table for an assignment but anytime I run the script, the formatting is messed up and it wouldn't repeat num1 for every new line.
(What I want this code to do is that the first number is a normal scalar (ie.12) and then the minimum and maximum is a bunch of different numbers (ie. 2-20), I want it to print 12x2=24 , 12x3 = 24, ... 12x20= 240)
This is the code I tried and for some reason its just always messed up.
num1 = input('What is your first number?:');
minnum2 = input ('What is your minimum of the second number?:');
maxnum2 = input('What is your maximum of the second number?:');
num2 = minnum2:1:maxnum2;
product = num1 * num2;
table = [num2;product];
fprintf ('%f x %2.0f = %3.0f \n',num1, table);

The first line would always be correct but after that it just all messes up.

You should avoid using table as a variable name, since you're shadowing the in-built function table

You are just missing 3rd parameter for printing. And use for loop for simplicity. Please check the below code.
for k=1:length(num2)
fprintf ('%2.0f x %2.0f = %3.0f \n',num1, table(1,k),table(2,k));
end


You can add a row to your table which is num1 repeated to the same size as num2, then just print the whole table in your format:
tbl = [num1*ones(size(num2)); num2; product];
fprintf('%d x %d = %d \n', tbl);

Output:
3 x 1 = 3 
3 x 2 = 6 
3 x 3 = 9 
3 x 4 = 12 
3 x 5 = 15 
3 x 6 = 18 
3 x 7 = 21 
3 x 8 = 24 
3 x 9 = 27 
3 x 10 = 30 
3 x 11 = 33 
3 x 12 = 36 

Note that the orientation of tbl matters here, the way you had it already works because the placeholders will populate the output string columns-first, since MATLAB is column-major, i.e. the first column is [3; 1; 3] so they are the first three digits used in the printed output 3 x 1 = 3.
